Apache Spark not finishes last task of stage without any logs or spilling in a loop
I have job running on spark 2.4.4 on hdfs cluster. It reads and joins two sources and does some processing of this data. Job is quite massive. shuffle-partitions are set up to 10000.
Job ends up on last task of one of the stages
First scenario:
24/07/30 07:20:00 WARN expressions.RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
24/07/30 07:20:00 WARN expressions.RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Memory used in task 158596
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@c437ba3: 14.6 GB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter@d451207: 64.0 MB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.FixedLengthRowBasedKeyValueBatch@78ce3e2b: 64.0 MB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.VariableLengthRowBasedKeyValueBatch@5f53250: 64.0 MB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@2085c96d: 256.0 KB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter@714737fd: 32.0 KB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: Acquired by org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@30fe0610: 256.0 KB
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: 0 bytes of memory were used by task 158596 but are not associated with specific consumers
24/07/30 07:20:01 INFO memory.TaskMemoryManager: 15838248960 bytes of memory are used for execution and 114520823 bytes of memory are used for storage
24/07/30 07:20:07 INFO sort.UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 100 spilling sort data of 2.0 GB to disk (0  time so far)

There is some data-skew which causes spill to disk. But it is the loop, nothing progressing.
I tried less executors - in this scenario there was no spill to disk, but no logs at all, and job beginning to not doing anything at the same point.
What can cause that?
I tried to run job with less executors and substantially increased memory.

Mots likely you have not even distribution of join keys. That results that 1 or couple tasks in join stage stuck while others complete. Check join key distribution in you datasets (for each dataset do groupBy join key and produce count, order by count desc and show top 100 keys). Also, do not use logs to investigate performance of spark jobs, use Spark UI instead.
